# Spring/Thymeleaf - Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I am new to Spring and Thymeleaf, and I do not know what went wrong here.
When submitting my form, I get `THIS` error:

`There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400). Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'br.com.teste.segware.domain.post.Post'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value 'Some text...'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Sometext..." org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'br.com.teste.segware.domain.post.Post'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value 'Some text...'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Sometext..."`

Here is my `Post` class: (I use Lombok, so the getters and setters are self-generated)

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post implements Serializable {

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 800)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String post;
}
```

My Controller:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @Autowired
    private PostService postService;

    @PostMapping("/savePost")
    String savePost(@ModelAttribute("post") Post post) {
        postService.savePost(post);
    
        return "redirect:/";
   }
}
```

And my HTML form:

```
<form method="post" th:object="${post}" th:action="@{/savePost}">
            <fieldset>
                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" />
            
                <label for="name">Nome:</label> <br/>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" th:field="*{nome}" placeholder="Nome..." /> <br/><br/>
                
                <label for="post">O que você gostaria de dizer?</label> <br/>
                <textarea id="post" name="post" th:field="*{post}" ></textarea> <br/><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Postar" />
            </fieldset>
</form>
```

Why is this thing trying to convert the `<textarea>` from `String` to some  number with `NumberFormat` stuff ?

The `Entity` named `Post` clearly declares the field `post` as a `String`. So why does Spring thinks it is some kind of Number when submitting? Obviously, when I put some numbers in `textarea`, it saves to the database. But I need `String` to be saved...

Someone please enlighten me.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Here is the Repository AND Service Class, just to be sure.

Service...

```
@Service
public class PostService {

    @Autowired
    private PostRepository postRepository;

    public void savePost(Post post) {
        postRepository.save(post);
    }
}
```

Repo...

```
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Integer> {

}
```

Comment: Do you have any other Post domain object in your setup, or is the Post entity directly accessed in the controller/page?

Could you also post the repository class?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! I edited the question with all the code I have until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a name collision since both the object name and the variable name are same (in your case, post).

Either change the column name in the entity class to other than post and then change in the html. Or, change the backing object name in the controller and html to something other than post. Both are working for me.

Comment: That was it! I Changed to column name and then in the HTML.
I think I used too many "post" words! Thank you very much!